# Vertical Navigation with text Pushing Issue

Tags: html, css

I want to make a vertical navigation with text and lines right next to text But, I have got a little issue in my Navigation. Its when I put some text next to a horizontal line to make a navigation link. The text size pushes the Line to right side.

```css
body {
  background-color: #663333;
}

#MainNavContainer {
  height: 100%;
}

.MainNav {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 0 !important;
}

.MainNav li {
  margin: 5px;
}

.MainNav li a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.MainNav li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.MainNav li a span {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.NavLine {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.NavTxt {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Asap Condensed;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainNavContainer">
  <ul class="MainNav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="NavLine"></span>
        <span class="NavTxt">HOME</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="NavLine"></span>
        <span class="NavTxt">SERVICES</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the snippet on CodePen:

```
<https://codepen.io/ZedandWhite/pen/NaXqEL>
```

Please suggest me some code to fix this Problem !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution. You can get the desired output by setting `min-width` or `width` to `.MainNav li a`. Check below snippet.

```css
body {
  background-color: #663333;
}

#MainNavContainer {
  height: 100%;
}

.MainNav {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 0 !important;
}

.MainNav li {
  margin: 5px;
}

.MainNav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.MainNav li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.MainNav li a span {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.NavLine {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.NavTxt {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Asap Condensed;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainNavContainer">
  <ul class="MainNav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="NavLine"></span>
        <span class="NavTxt">HOME</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="NavLine"></span>
        <span class="NavTxt">SERVICES</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If flex-box is acceptable, will the following solution suffice?

```
.MainNav li a {
    /* change the properties to the following instead of inline block */
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #663333;
}

#MainNavContainer {
  height: 100%;
}

.MainNav {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 0 !important;
}

.MainNav li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.MainNav li a {
  width: 100%;
  //display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.MainNav li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.MainNav li a span {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.NavLine {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.NavTxt {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Asap Condensed;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainNavContainer">
  <ul class="MainNav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="NavLine"></span>
        <span class="NavTxt">HOME</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="NavLine"></span>
        <span class="NavTxt">SERVICES</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The padding on the parent `li` can be adjusted to your requirement